# Stored procedure in SQL that checks if index not exist then create

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

My SQL script is running perfectly when I execute it.

Now the problem is when I check on table indexes this script does not create index.

Below is the script

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test 
     @TableName nvarchar(128)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

    SET @Sql  = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = Index_type) 
                     CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX Index_type 
                         ON ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N'(CustomerId) ON "PRIMARY"';
END

EXECUTE test customer
```

Comment: `name = Indextype`???  What is that supposed to be doing?

Comment: As well as the issue @GordonLinoff mentions any check against `sys.indexes` should also be checking `object_id` - index names don't have to be unique across objects

Comment: And you create a `@Sql` string but don't execute it

Comment: that is just a index name that  i create

Comment: if this script is wrong then why it execute successfully. Please help to correct script

Comment: There's a number of issues with the script in itself (e.g. missing quotes around `'index_type` in your `IF NOT EXISTS()`, or the fact that you never do anything with your variable `sql` (presumably you want to execute it?). The fact it doesn't check it exists on the relevant table. Or the fact that you are missing quotes when execute it (should be `EXECUTE test 'Customer';` or the fact that as it is posted `EXECUTE test customer` is part of the procedure itself because it appears in the same batch.

Comment: Forgetting all of this though, what purpose does this procedure actually serve? It would only work on tables that contain a `CustomerID` column and where that column should be the clustering index, and this doesn't feel like something that ever needs to be done dynamically, it should be done once at the point of creating the table, and then never done again.

Comment: Yes GarethD you are right. Actually I want to create a script that dynamically check in multiple tables if index is not exist then create

Comment: Yes, but why does this need to be done dynamically? This implies you need to check on the fly if the index exists, whereas logically you would only need to create a clustered index once at the same time the table is created, so this should be in your create table script, and not a procedure that calls some very flaky dynamic SQL

Comment: This sounds like we have an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) here.

Comment: in simple words i just want to creat sql script that check if index not exist in table then create it

Comment: Honestly how many tables do you have in your database that need that exact clustering ID? If it's only one or two then why do you need dynamic SQL? There is definitely something more going on here

Comment: for just 1 and 2 its not issue but i have 15 tables in my database

Comment: If you only need to create these indexes once on these 15 tables, it still shouldn't require a stored procedure, just write 15 create index scripts. It will take about 10 minutes and then it is done and you never need to worry about it again. If you are going to create further tables in the future, just create the index at the same time the table is created. If you are going to drop clustered indexes, then simply disable any process that does this, it is a terrible idea

Answer (score 0):

This is possible (link to very simple demo at the end of the answer but this doesn't account for all scenarios by any means), but I really wouldn't bother doing this dynamically. If you are creating any index dynamically it is a bit of a code smell, let alone a clustered one.

The issue is, that you can work out if a table has a CustomerID column, and if it contains unique values, and if there is no clustered index already, but none of this tells you if a clustered index is appropriate. Consider the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
    OrderDate DATE NOT NULL,
    ....
);
```

This has no clustered index, has a table called CustomerID, CustomerID may be unique if it is empty or has only a few orders in, so is a candidate for a clustered index to be created on CustomerID. But CustomerID is clearly not the appropriate clustering key here. There is no script in the world that can tell you how you intend your tables to be used, you could get very very close using best design practices to try and work it out, or even standard conventions such as column ordinals, but nothing will ever do this perfectly.

A better approach would be to do this as a one off task, you could identify all the tables with a customerID column, and even give yourself a template create index script as follows:

```
SELECT t.name,
        CreateIndexScript = CONCAT('CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_', 
                                    NULLIF(s.name, 'dbo') + '_', t.name, '_CustomerID ON ',
                                    QUOTENAME(s.name), '.', QUOTENAME(t.name), ' (CustomerID);')
FROM    sys.tables AS t
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
            ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns AS c WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id AND c.name = 'CustomerID')
AND     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes AS i WHERE i.object_id = t.object_id AND i.type = 1)
```

You can then review each table thrown up by this script to see if creating a clustered index on `CustomerID` is appropriate, and then run the script(s) manually. Once the index is created it shouldn't be dropped, so you don't have to worry about this being run on a regular basis.

**[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c0f38bd94e623fe36a10863988603db)**

Comment: Thanks garethd . But i have different table names and every table has different column name. Not all the tables have CUSTOMER_ID column. actually i need to check on every table if an index exists(I do not know on which column it exist). If it does not exist then i need to create an index on any column.

Comment: the reason i was going for dynamic sql is that there may be 200 tables. and i can not hardcode it for 200 tables. so i wanted to write a procedure that chooses table name from list of tables dynamically. then it checks index on it,. if it does not exist then create it. so as u see that i would be getting table name dynamically , i also need to get column name dynamically

Comment: So given a particular table name, how would you know which column is supposed to be the clustering key so that you can dynamically create an index on it? How do you know it should only have a single column in the clustering key? It is entirely possible multiple columns may make up the clustering key, particularly in the case of junction tables.